# How can I use javascript to get a substring of whatever is between two parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, substring, lastindexof

I am trying to return just "AA" using javascript.

This doesn't work.

```
var myStr = "Item Code Alpha Tengo (AA)"; 
var newStr = myStr.substring("(",myStr.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

Comment: Quick regex: `var aa = mystr.match(/\((.+)\)/)[1]`

Comment: substring takes a numeric index as first arg, but you are passing it the string "(" instead

Comment: so something like var newStr = myStr.substring(myStr.IndexOf("("),myStr.lastIndexOf(")"));

Comment: Use indexOf var newStr = myStr.substring(myStr.indexOf("(")+1,myStr.lastIndexOf(")"));

Comment: try this if your string has only one '(' and ')' var newStr = myStr.substring(myStr.indexOf("(") + 1,myStr.indexOf(")"));

Comment: both are same wht da difference both answers you both copied from comment

Comment: both are same wht da difference both answers you both copied from comment

Comment: @elclanrs—if you don't mind seeing an error when no match is found.

Comment: @RobG: Right, I usually do this `aa = (mystr.match(/\((.+)\)/) || [,null])[1]`.

Comment: if you look at the time the comment & the answer posted on same time, and yes there is a difference look carefully

Comment: Look well .. Both answers differ .. Poor guy don't have eyes....!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do:

```
var myStr = 'Item Code Alpha Tengo (AA)';
myStr.replace(/^[^(]*\(|\)[^)]*$/g, ''); // AA
```

or the simpler:

```
myStr.replace(/.*\(|\).*/g,'')
```